Power BI - Buttons, Bookmarks & Slicers. Creating different conditions to flick through
I have created a report in Power BI which has multiple visuals including 2 tables with important information, a map and slicers for users to select a country, and a sponsor (and more) from a dropdown list.

I have added an image of this with sensitive data blacked out.
Then, I have created 3 buttons (linked to bookmarks) to represent All Sites (Standard view), Low Performing sites (filters the data so that only sites with >2 pts rands >0 ) and Non-Performing sites( filters the data so that only sites where there is a non blank RTE date & 0 or Blank pts rands).
I used slicers to create these bookmarks so that I could filter the data as required, and hid them to create the bookmark views for Low and Non performing sites.
Is there a way to keep the selection of country and sponsor intact, but to still be able to click between these conditions?
i.e. I want the use to be able to open the report, choose a country, choose a sponsor and then change between viewing ALL of the data, the Low Performers or the Non-Performers (without having to select the country & sponsor slicers again).
Any and all suggestions would be super useful!

After many attempts I decided to ignore the use of bookmarks completely and create 3 separate pages where I was then able to set the action of a button to be page navigation, and on said pages create my filters and conditions to be set up how I needed.

I would not use bookmarks to solve this problem. Rather create a calculated column on your table that returns values "Low performing sites" and non-preforming sites. And then create a slicer based on this new calculated column.

You have to uncheck this for your bookmarks:

But this will remove the selection of your hidden slicers as well.

Right, so it doesn't solve my issue then? This was literally the first thing I tried and completely removes the views I need bookmarks for.

Yes. I would suggest you approach differently with your bookmarks. Duplicate your visuals 3 times, apply visual-level filters, adjust your bookmarks, and remove the Data check. One other solution that comes to mind is using parameter to filter your visuals, and that way you won't have duplications. But I don't know if this is applicable in your case.
